# JS function with PHP vars onclick in <a> tag is not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick

The following code is in a single PHP file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
function pipeDelete(topicid, msgid, action) {
  if (topicid == 0) {
    var ans = confirm("Delete the topic?");
  } else {
    var ans = confirm("Delete this comment?");
  }
  if (ans) {
    var dest = 'msg_transact.php';
  $.post(dest, {topicid:topicid, msgid:msgid, action:action}, function() {
    $("#" + msgid).hide("slow");
          });
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<?php
// some code, $row['topic_id'] and $row['msg_id'] are integers
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // some code
  echo '<div id="' . $row['msg_id'] . '">';
  $deletelink = '<a href="#" onclick="pipeDelete(\'' . $row['topic_id'] .
    '\', \'' . $row['msg_id'] . '\', \'deletepost\')">Delete</a>';
  // some code
  echo $deletelink;
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

The problem is, when I click on the "Delete" link, the page just reloads ('#' is appended at the end of the URL) and nothing happens. The onclick event does not run and the function is not called. I don't think jquery or *// some code* interferes because for that to happen I should at least get the combo box isn't it?

Whats the problem that is stopping the onclick event on calling the JS function?

SOLUTION: Write 2 separate script tags - one for jquery src and other for js code.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">/* javascript code */</script>`

Answer (score 2):

`onclick` needs to "`return false`" to prevent the default action (following the # anchor there)

---

Now, it seems that you're using jQuery.
That said, why not making a non-intrusive code assuming you're using html5 ? :)

**Note that id mustn't be only numerical in HTML**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.deletelink').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var topicid = $(this).attr('data-row'), msgid = $(this).attr('data-msg'), action = $(this).attr('data-action');
  if (topicid == 0) {
    var ans = confirm("Delete the topic?");
  } else {
    var ans = confirm("Delete this comment?");
  }
  if (ans) {
    var dest = 'msg_transact.php';
  $.post(dest, {topicid:topicid, msgid:msgid, action:action}, function() {
    $("#row-" + msgid).hide("slow");
          });
  }
  }); 
</script>
</head>
<?php
// some code, $row['topic_id'] and $row['msg_id'] are integers
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // some code
  echo '<div id="row-' . $row['msg_id'] . '">';
  $deletelink = '<a href="#" data-row="' . $row['topic_id'] . '" data-msg="' . $row['msg_id'] . '" data-action="deletelink" class="deletelink">Delete</a>';
  // some code
  echo $deletelink;
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

See an example corrsponding with pseudo-html generated on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q67Vx/1/)

Comment: I tried this.
`onclick="pipeDelete(); return false;"`
But that didn't work either...

Comment: The anchor doesn't reload the page - there's no need for return false.

Comment: If I don't write `return false;`, the page URL is appended with # at the end and nothing else happens.

Comment: On your example, you wrote `onclick="return false; pipeDelete(..)` which won't right obviously.

Comment: Thanks man! But I already resolved the issue before your new edit. The problem was only that I wrote JS code inside `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> /* code, functions */ </script>`
This is wrong. The problem was solved by writing separate 2 script tags, one for jquery src and other for the code, like you wrote in your edit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

two options:

substitute the `"#"` with `"javascript:pipeDelete(..)"` and remove the onclick attribute or add the click event through jquery, where you are able to prevent the default behaviour.

E.g:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
  // do stuff
  ....
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behaviour of a link
});
```

Comment: The 2nd method, should I write that inside pipeDelete() in <script> tags? And if it is, all the code will be in _// do stuff_?

Comment: The 1st method, on substituting with #, nothing happens at all, the page doesn't even reload.

Answer (score 0):

The problems are HERE:

```
$("#" + msgid + "\"").hide("slow");
```

Change to:

```
$("#" + msgid).hide("slow");
```

AND here:

```
$row['msg_id'] . '\', \"deletepost\")">Delete</a>';
```

Change to:

```
$row['msg_id'] . '\', \'deletepost\')">Delete</a>';
```

And here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
```

Change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/AUTrX/

You don't need to change the `"#"` or `return false;` - The `"#"` will NOT reload the page, it just moves the page to wherever the internal anchor is if you've provided and specified one .

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle.  It works.  Work backwards from there to add in your code one piece at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome site! But, my code and that are same except I've used PHP vars instead of foo and bar and also I've echo the tags.
If I don't write `return false;`, the page URL is appended with # at the end and nothing else happens.

Comment: They are not the same. I used 'foo' and 'bar' because I don't have access to your database.  This is what you have: http://jsfiddle.net/gJS34/  It doesn't work.  What I have at the link in my answer does work.  If there are more issues than that, you'll need to add a lot more information because nobody has access to your post url or your database to get the rows of data.

Comment: The problem was only with `<script>` tags. I edited the post. And thanks for your earlier changes, those were necessary.

Comment: I sure want to, but I'm new and don't even have a reputation of min required 15...

Comment: Ah... I updated my answer to include your parts of the answer.  Now you can just accept it as a complete answer.